# Is there a way to insert an internal anchor/bookmark into MS Word document and later reference it?

Tags: microsoft-word, bookmarks

In HTML it is pretty easy to insert an anchor (or a bookmark) into a document and reference it from the same document. Can I do the same in MS Word doc?

PS. Without importing HTML content into it.

Comment: Do you mean you want to use [references](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/inserting-cross-references-HA001186680.aspx) and add hyperlinks to the references?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't mention what version of Word you are using, but if you have 2007 or later, you'll want to look at [Bookmarks](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-or-delete-bookmarks-in-a-word-document-or-outlook-message-f68d781f-0150-4583-a90e-a4009d99c2a0) which can be used to identify a location or a selection of text that you name and identify for future reference.

You can use bookmarks along with [cross-references](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-cross-reference-300b208c-e45a-487a-880b-a02767d9774b) for the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Very nice, it worked! One thing I need to learn though -- When I insert a link to existing bookmark by doing the "Cross-reference" is there any way to automatically mark it with a different color like it's done in most HTML?

Comment: Not as easily as one would hope. Assuming you checked the box "Insert as Hyperlink", the cross-reference will automatically get associated with the "Hyperlink" style. *Unfortunately* the attributes of that style (blue, underlined font) are *suppressed* for cross-references!  Take a look at [this website](http://wordfaqs.mvps.org/FormatCrossReferences.htm) for some clues.

Comment: I disagree. It is a powerful tool, once you get the hang of it. But I do admit that it is quirky, and the learning curve for styles and formatting is particularly challenging.

Comment: These links are both dead.

Comment: links have been updated.